# ffmpeg video File incomplete error when downloaded chrome version 69

Tags: ffmpeg, jasmine, protractor

I am generating video in my protractor tests in Linux machine. The video is .mov format for chrome version 69.0.3497
.Downloading the .mov file give "File Incomplete Error" during download.

```
   jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new VideoReporter({
        baseDirectory: './test-output/videos',
        saveSuccessVideos: true,
        ffmpegCmd: '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
        ffmpegArgs: [
            '-y',
            '-r', '30',
            '-f', 'x11grab',
            '-s', '1280x1024',
            '-i', process.env.DISPLAY,
            '-g', '300',
            '-vcodec', 'mpeg4'
        ]
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

It auto fixed itself. Not sure how. Maybe a network issue.